# How to display the Newsfeed within a Web Part

Tags: 2013, web-part, newsfeed

I have page where I'd like to display the Newsfeed (My Site) of the user currently logged on?

It's for a site where the community feature will be utilised so auto displaying the logged on users newsfeed on the homepage of this site will allow users to see updates within the community forum everytime they visit the page.

As email alerts are poorly implemented in SP2013 community sites, I feel this is the best way for users to keep updated with what's going on in the forum.

I've tried using the web page viewer but it comes with an error stating this can be viewed in an iframe.

Environment is SharePoint 2013 Enterprise On Prem.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the newsfeed webpart?

using poweshell and looking at this list you want to enable 6928B0E5-5707-46a1-AE16-D6E52522D52B

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18729.sharepoint-2013-list-of-features-id-displayname-compatibilitylevel-and-scopes.aspx

in powershell do the following:

```
Enable-SPFeature –identity 6928B0E5-5707-46a1-AE16-D6E52522D52B -URL http://yoursiteurl
```

now goto the page in question (homepage) and add webpart to the page, this webpart would be located under `Social Collaboration` and is called `newsfeed`.

follow this doc for more info:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219700.aspx

and

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382643.aspx